# For a ring $R,$ there is no injective map from $R^m \hookrightarrow R^n$ for $m > n.$ (verification)

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Suppose $R$ is a ring and we have an $R$-module homomorphism of free modules $R^{n + 1} \hookrightarrow R^n.$ Then take a submodule of $R^{n + 1}$ that is isomorphic to $R.$ Say for any $r \in R,$ we can associate it to $(0, \ldots, 0, r)$ or even $r$ to $(r, \ldots, r).$ Now the image of this submodule under this injective map is also isomorphic to $R.$ Then taking the quotient of this submodule yields $R^{n + 1}/R = R^n \hookrightarrow R^n/R = R^{n - 1}.$ Proceeding in this manner yields $R \hookrightarrow 0$ which implies $R = 0.$ Does this work? Any comments are appreciated. (I guess this says the injectivity only holds when $R$ is the trivial ring but this is trivial...)

Comment: Are you assuming that $R$ is commutative?

Comment: I did not assume that $R$ was commutative.

Comment: This is definitely wrong. The image being isomorphic to $R$ does not imply that the quotient by this image is isomorphic to the quotient by $R$.

Comment: Hmm ok how about the following: Take a submodule of $R^n$ isomorphic to $R.$ Let $f$ denote the injective map from $R^{n + 1}$ to $R^n.$ Then $f^{-1}(R)$ is a submodule of $R^{n + 1}$ that is isomorphic to a submodule of $R.$ Hence, we have a series of injective maps $R^{n + 1}/R \hookrightarrow R^{n + 1}/f^{-1}(R) \hookrightarrow R^n/R = R^{n - 1}.$ Then can we continue using this process?

Comment: @伽罗瓦 There are non-commutative rings without IBN.

Comment: Wait sorry what is IBN?

Comment: @伽罗瓦 IBN: Invariant Basis Number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is wrong because (with your notation) $R/R$ may not be zero. For an example, first note:

> If $R$ is an integral domain and $0\neq r\in R$, then $(r)\cong R$ as $R$-modules.

The isomorphism is given by multiplication with $r$. Once we have this, consider the polynomial ring (say, with complex coefficients) on infinitely many variables:

$$R=\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\dots] $$

Then the ideal $(x_1)$ is isomorphic to $R$. But the quotient $R/(x_1)$ is isomorphic to $R$ (as a ring, because they satisfy the same universal properties), and in particular it is non-zero.

Comment: I see...but is it possible to salvage my proof? Perhaps we can explicitly take $R$ to be $0 \times \ldots \times 0 \times R$ as a submodule of $R^n?$ Or would we run into the same problem again...

Comment: @伽罗瓦 you can pick that submodule on the left hand side, but you don't have any control over its image on the right hand side (because the injective map is given, not of your choice). In particular it could happen that its image is such a pathological example, so the argument still doesn't work

Comment: What about picking it on the right hand side and using my argument I wrote in the comments. (Thank you by the way)

Comment: @伽罗瓦 as the comments below the question suggest, you need to use that your ring is commutative. IBN means invariant basis number. You can check it out on Wikipedia for example